# re.sub matching pattern but not getting the desired output

Tags: python, formatting

Im trying to make a python script to break and go on to a new line every time it reaches a word with a capital letter. So far so good, the pattern is matched, however for some reason it stops inserting new lines into the string at some point. I am not seeing any change in the pattern and the list with the matches shows that the expression works and catches all the capital letters all the way to the end.
Here is my code:

```
def new_line(name):
    fr = open(name, 'r')
    string = fr.read()
    m = re.findall('\s+[A-Z]\w*', string,re.MULTILINE)
    for i in m:
        j = str(i)
        print("These are the list items:"+j+"\n")
        n = re.sub('(\s[A-Z])',r'\n\1',string,re.MULTILINE)
        fw = open('output_file', 'w')
        fw.write(n)
        fw.close()
        print('/////////////////////////////////////////////')
        print("Output :\n"+n)
        print(m)
new_line('task.txt')
```

Desired output should be:

Grange; and, to my agreeable disappointment, she behaved infinitely better than

I dared to expect.

She seemed almost over-fond of

Mr.

Linton and even to his sister she showed plenty of affection.

They were both very attentive to her comfort, certainly.

It was not the thorn bending to the honeysuckles, but the honeysuckles embracing the thorn.

There etc...

Instead of:

Grange; and, to my agreeable disappointment, she behaved infinitely better than
 I dared to expect.
 She seemed almost over-fond of
 Mr.
 Linton and even to his sister she showed plenty of affection. They were both very attentive to her comfort, certainly. It was not the thorn bending to the honeysuckles, but the honeysuckles embracing the thorn. There

As i have stated above, the list shows that re.findall catches all the words after "over-fond of Mr.Linton"

Comment: Aside from the regex issue, each write to 'output_file' wipes out the previous file contents. I suspect you actually want to append to the  previous contents. BTW, `string` isn't a great variable name since it's the name of a standard module.

Comment: Yes, those are both good points. Im not getting problems with writing to output since its all written at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, the most underutilized tool in the `re` toolbox is `split`.  If I understand your problem correctly, this will solve it perfectly:

> inputstr = ''' Grange; and, to my agreeable disappointment, she
>   behaved infinitely better than I dared to expect. She seemed almost
>   over-fond of Mr. Linton and even to his sister she showed plenty of
>   affection. They were both very attentive to her comfort, certainly. It
>   was not the thorn bending to the honeysuckles, but the honeysuckles
>   embracing the thorn. There'''

```
import re

result = re.split(r'\s+(?=[A-Z])', inputstr)
print('\n'.join(result))
```

This results in:

```
Grange; and, to my agreeable disappointment, she behaved infinitely better than
I dared to expect.
She seemed almost over-fond of
Mr.
Linton and even to his sister she showed plenty of affection.
They were both very attentive to her comfort, certainly.
It was not the thorn bending to the honeysuckles, but the honeysuckles embracing the thorn.
There
```

Comment: Thank you ! That seems to do the job nicely